# how to pass uid in script for routing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

how can i pass the userid/uid along with the profile link (route: '/u/' + this.$auth.user.id) ? What i have below doesn't work.

my code is as follows (using nuxt)

```html
<script>
import profilePic from './profilePic';

export default {
  components: { profilePic },

  data: () => ({
    links: [
      {
        icon: 'mdi-account-circle-outline',
        title: 'Profile',
        route: '/u/' + this.$auth.user.id
      },
      { icon: 'mdi-clipboard-multiple-outline', title: 'My Lists', route: '/' },
      { icon: 'mdi-logout', title: 'Logout', route: '/u/logout' }
    ]
  })
</script>
```

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by *not working*? is the route link `/u/undefined`?

Comment: change `data: () => ({})`  to `data () {}`. You will encounter wrong context issue if uses arrow function.

Comment: @Daniel, i get this error "TypeError Cannot read property '$auth' of undefined"

Comment: @Sphinx, i updated it to be `data () { code },` but i get 2 errors 
80:5   error    Unexpected labeled statement *no-labels
80:12  error    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression *no-unused-expressions

Comment: @dishguy you need to change it to `data () { return { links: ... } }`. Alternatively, use `data: vm => ({ links: ... })` but use `vm.$auth.user.id`